# Cannot read saved image files in python/django

Tags: django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
url = 'http://www.wired.com/category/science/'
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=None,
            headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
    )
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    html = f.read()
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


    title_tag = soup.title

    for link in soup.find_all('img'):

        alt_data =link.get('alt')

        if not alt_data:
            alt_data= 'no alt text'

        URL=link.get('src')
        import uuid
        random_value = uuid.uuid1()
        IMAGE = URL.rsplit('/', 1)[1]

        content =urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, IMAGE)
        from django.core.files import File

        cntent_typ=ContentType.objects.get(name='image')
        obj = Content.objects.create(content_type=cntent_typ, url=url, title=alt_data, text=alt_data, image=File(open(content[0])))
        obj.save()
```

**When i tried to open the saved image file manually.It shows :Could not load image xcxxxcx.jpg
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x21)**
How can i solve this issue?

Comment: You probably need `urllib.request.urlretrieve(urlparse.urljoin(url, URL), IMAGE)` instead of `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, IMAGE)`.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir ..Got..UnicodeDecodeError at /
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working example of your code (minus saving the image). Only thing I changed is what I mentioned in my comment i.e. use `urllib.parse.urljoin(url, URL)` but the error you mentioned in your comment was because your URL had some Unicode characters. So I used `from django.utils.encoding import iri_to_uri` to encode the URL properly.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import uuid
from django.utils.encoding import iri_to_uri 


url = 'http://www.wired.com/category/science/'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=None,
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
html = f.read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


title_tag = soup.title

for link in soup.find_all('img'):

    alt_data =link.get('alt')

    if not alt_data:
        alt_data= 'no alt text'

    URL=link.get('src')
    random_value = uuid.uuid1()
    IMAGE = URL.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
    print(urljoin(url, iri_to_uri(URL)))
    content =urllib.request.urlretrieve(urljoin(url, iri_to_uri(URL)), IMAGE)
```